# How to delete first point from path which is drawn to android canvas

Tags: android, path, android-canvas

I want to draw a line on android canvas. This line must follow user's finger. I want to remove first point of path continuously. How to accomplish this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save all the points in a linkedlist. Redraw the path every time a point is added/removed (i.e clear the screen, draw line from p0 to p1, from p1 to p2...). After a point is added and there are already say 100 points then remove the first to keep the list down to a fixed size.